# R heatmap with fractions of discretise variables in row side

Tags: r, matrix, axis, heatmap

I have a few thousand observations of a handful of factors that I turn into discrete 1/0 values according to a minimum value per factor and I plot it in a heatmap.2 (red=1, black=0). This plots the combinations of, say, A+B+C+D being 1, combinations of 3 factors being 1, combinations of 2 factors, etc. I would like to have the fractions of these combinations plotted in the left-hand side vertical axis in the heatmap.2:

```
nentries=10000
ci=rainbow(nentries)
set.seed=1
mean=10
## Generate some data (4 factors)
i = data.frame(
  a=round(abs(rnorm(nentries,mean-2))),
  b=round(abs(rnorm(nentries,mean-1))),
  c=round(abs(rnorm(nentries,mean+1))),
  d=round(abs(rnorm(nentries,mean+2)))
  )
minvalue = 10
# Discretise values to 1 or 0
m0 = matrix(as.numeric(i>minvalue),nrow=nrow(i))
# Remove rows with all zeros
m = m0[rowSums(m0)>0,]
# Reorder with 1,1,1,1 on top
ms =m[order(as.vector(m %*% matrix(2^((ncol(m)-1):0),ncol=1)), decreasing=TRUE),]
rowci = rainbow(nrow(ms))
colci = rainbow(ncol(ms))
heatmap(ms,
        Rowv=NA,
        labRow=" ",
        keep.dendro = FALSE,
        col=c("black","red"),
        RowSideColors=rowci,
        ColSideColors=colci,
        )
```

RowSideColors is right now a rainbow with as many as nrow(ms) colours, and I would like instead to have the 1/0 combinations for the factors and a legend. Something like: `A+B+C+D 1%`, `B+C+D 10%`, etc, next to RowSideColors. Any ideas?

Comment: So what you want is to add a legend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a small number of row labels, one for each block? This should do the trick

```
colnames(ms)=LETTERS[1:4]
limits=c(which(!duplicated(ms)),nrow(ms))
l=length(limits)
toname=round((limits[-l]+ limits[-1])/2)
freq=(limits[-1]-limits[-l])/nrow(ms)

rn=rep("", nrow(ms))
for(i in toname) rn[i]=paste(colnames(ms)[which(ms[i,]==1)],collapse="")
rn[toname]=paste(rn[toname], ": ", sprintf( "%.5f", freq ), "%")

heatmap(ms, Rowv=NA, labRow=rn, col=c("black","red"))
```

It uses the fact that your data are already sorted to find the middle of each block (where we want a legend to appear), then creates a vector of legends which is empty for most rows, and contains the column names and the proportion for the rows where a legend should be displayed.

Comment: Brilliant! This is precisely what I was looking for!